# How do I make a single list (varying text lengths) into two equal columns without creating empty vertical space between the list items?

Tags: javascript, css, list

I have to deal with dynamic code that is being outputted via php, and I have only css and javascript at my disposal to use.

I have a single column of list items (not using

tags) that I need to divide into two columns (order doesn't matter). Currently, I gave every item a css of 'float: left;' and every other item (using javascript) a css of 'clear: left;' and with a pre-defined width so that they equally divide into two columns.

The problem though, is that in the current setup, when a list item on the left column is tall, the shorter list item on the right gains a empty white space beneath it.

Is there a way to code the list into two columns without creating any unnecessary vertical space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle.  Since you can use javascript I'm assuming you can load jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/r4zkp/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three three three three three three three three </li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>six</li>
        <li>seven</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.left_list, .right_list {
    float: left;
    width: 100px
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    left_list = $('li:even');
    right_list = $('li:odd');
    $('#wrapper').html('');
    $('#wrapper').append('<div class="left_list">');
    $('.left_list').html(left_list);
    $('#wrapper').append('<div class="right_list">');
    $('.right_list').html(right_list);
});

​
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack the elements in the list in a div. Then messure the height of the element holding the list. Now create a new list on the site. Itterate through the list elements and messure the height + margins + etc, and until the height of the list items are larger then half of the total height of the list items.

For every element after that you move them to the new list.

Here is a short example written in mootools and a fiddle if you want to try it. It should be easy to convert to jQuery or pure javascript. As you can see this gives a more even distribution of the elements.

```
var height = $('wrapper').getCoordinates().height;
var listHeight = 0;

var leftColumn = new Element('ul', {class: 'list'});
var rightColumn = new Element('ul', {class: 'list'});

$$('#wrapper li').each(function(li){
   listHeight = listHeight + li.getSize().y;

    if (listHeight < height/2){
        leftColumn.grab(li);
    }
    else{
        rightColumn.grab(li);                                   
    }
});
var wrapper = $('wrapper');
wrapper.getChildren().destroy();
wrapper.grab(leftColumn);
wrapper.grab(rightColumn);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7t324/1/

The really even way (without breaking a list item and not mind the order)
If you really want even distribution (and order is not important) then you could sort your list elements in height. And then you add one element to the left ul, next step is to add elements to the right ul until it's height is greater then the left. Then you do the same for the left, and so on.

If the look of it is to even (ordered in height) you could change the order of the list items a before you add them.